# Casting from char pointer to integer in C

Tags: c++, casting

I have a char type pointer array **buf** and I want to cast each element of it  to unsigned int and store it in an unsigned int or int **array** .

The thing is that the second code command of code below for casting returns me a negative value after casting in unsigned int whereas I am only expecting positive values from 0 to 255. Why is it returning me negative values when I am using unsigned it? What should I do that the casting in 2nd line of code returns me only positive values between 0 and 255?

```
int array [100];
array[l]=((unsigned int(buf[0]))*5));
```

Please help me with it.

Thank you.

Comment: how do you want to cast -10 to a positive number? what result do you expect?

Comment: What type is buf? Why do you not show real code (the code you gave has at least two errors)? is the value of buf[0] in any way constraint, or what makes you think that multiplying it with 5 will always lead to something between 0 and 255?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are printing the variable values as signed instead of unsigned? Otherwise provide a complete example that fails.

Comment: In the heading you say C, but you've tagged the post with C++. Which do you mean? From the code it seems you mean C.

Answer (score 2):

The second instruction is way too complex.

Divide your instructions into separate lines.

- In one line, access the actually stored value in your "char type
  pointer array".
- In a subsequent line, convert it to whatever you want.

This will help you to diagnose the problem, and will make the code much more readable and maintainable.

Comment: But the problem remains the same, it isn't an answer to my problem.

Comment: True. But it would make it easier to get good answers, because people would understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

You want `*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&buf[0])))` not `(unsigned int(buf[0]))`. Don't forget to cast that to an `int` *before* you multiply it by 5.

Comment: The reinterpret_cast is not only not nice (code smell) but also not necessary, he can assign buf[0] (assuming it is a const char* or similar) to an unsigned char, and from there assign to an unsigned int, and from there multipl and assign to an int. Also the extra cast to an int before multiplying by 5 is likely not necessary, as a value between 0 and 255 ( assuming 8 bit chars) will just do it fine too.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: How can I do this, is the following line fine:

int temp=(unsigned int(unsigned char(buf[0])))*5;

Comment: @user1486008: follow the advice of Daniel Daranas and split this up into single lines to understand what it is doing.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: This works perfect:

int temp=(unsigned int(unsigned char(buf[0])))*5;

Comment: @user1486008: Funny, what is the language you use that compiles this? It certainly is not C++ (as your question was tagged)

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Assigning an out-of-range value to a type is *much* worse than casting a pointer -- especially when casting the pointer is what he actually, specifically wants to do.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Yes this is a C++ command and works perfect :)

Comment: @user1486008: Funny, I wonder what compiler you have... http://ideone.com/m90f5

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make `array` declared as `unsigned int`. Also, use `unsigned char` to cast instead of `unsigned int` and then assign it to `array` elements. This is because the conversion of negative values to an unsigned target type will be according to C++ standard section 4.7 paragraph 2.

```
unsigned int array [100];
array[l]=((unsigned char(buf[0]))*5));
```